# HTML-CSS: Avoid Next Line Before Input Field

Tags: html, css, templates

A had a theme in which I am making changes.
My code ges as folllows:

```
<div class="box four last">
    <!-- box title-->
    <h5>
        <a href="products.html">SEND QUERY</a>
    </h5>
    <!-- text-->
    <p>
        <!--Text Here-->                
    </p>
    <a href="#" title="" class="small_button">Read More</a>
</div>
```

I want to insert a form at the place where it is written text here.
So I insert the following code in there:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST" style="display:inline;">
    <div><label>Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name"></div>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email">
    Phone: <input type="text" name="phone">
    Website:<input type="text" name="website">
    Message:<textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

And here is what I get as output:
[image: Output]
(The last one - Send Query)

See in this, the input fields come in the next line, but what I want is that it comes in front of the text (ex. `Name: <textfield>`)
So that I can minimize the form length by making it around 50% shorter so that it goes with the other thing

**What I have tried:** I thought that it has something to do with the class "box four last", so I searched for the exact string among all the css files but could not find, however I found a lot of occurrences of 'box', 'four' etc.all those mainly had just the width described. I also tried removing the div tag but it made it worse, I have also tried putting inline attribute in from tag.

There is 1 relevant CSS File:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
```

stlye.css -> http://jsfiddle.net/4sEhE/2/

**Update 1**
In style.css I found this:

```
/* Four*/.box.four{width:220px; }/*
```

**Update 2** Even if I lessen the width of the input(by adding more to the end of css file), the input field comes in next line :P

[image]

Comment: Well. we would need the `CSS` to help but even then you should be able to work it out. If you want them on the same line, you will have to reduce the size of the `input`, my guess is they are `100%` width of the parent leaving no room for anything else on that line.

Comment: @Ruddy I will just try to reduce it size once and check otherwise i will upload the css Files

Comment: You can just make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Makes life easier for us.

Comment: @Ruddy 3 separate right?

Comment: `3 separate right?` Not following you there, what?

Comment: There are 3 different Css files so you want me to put each one's code in there one by one and then give you the link of those right?

Comment: Well I'm not going to look through 3 `CSS` files. You could get the relevant `CSS` and create a JSFiddle of the problem as is. I'm not going to do it all for you. If you get all relevant code in a JSFiddle then I will fix the problem

Comment: @Ruddy: I think this is the concerned file and i have given a jsfiddle link, kindly see. I am still trying to cut short..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you are following same structure as it is there in the following demo

OLD Demo. `http://jsbin.com/yotirifo/1/`

Updated Demo http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/4sEhE/20/

Comment: God knows, sorry i am new to this and i am trying my best to figure out something specific...

Comment: you can see I've added CSS specificity there so the `<p>` haven't conflict with your CSS. I've added `form.contact_form` and then give apply the `class name` to `form`.

Comment: Even if i lessen the width the input comes in next line only: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h2mlz0u420cyt1d/abcd.PNG

Comment: I am working offline, but i showed a image though update 2. See it once and tell me the files you need i ll upload them on dropbox

Comment: can you give me the html page and relative CSS

Comment: HTML(index.html): https://www.dropbox.com/s/4dqtnz6a4pwd8zj/index.html
CSS(stlye.css): https://www.dropbox.com/s/8bqoajzacwm7cm9/style.css

Comment: can you increase the width of class `box` right now its 220px.. give the more width to it and reduce left margin from `20px` to `10px` color:#848484;}

Comment: if its work for you now, please accept the answer and close it.

Comment: `.box.four{width:220px;}` change width `220px` as per your need.

Comment: It is not that, but something else... can we chat for a minute?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48480/discussion-between-daksh-shah-and-kheema-pandey)